# How to delete an external table in Hive when the hdfs path has been deleted?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, external-tables

I've removed my HDFS path `/user/abc`, and some Hive tables were stored in `/user/abc/data/abc.db` , with a `rm -R` command.

Despite having my regular tables correctly deleted with Hive SQL, my **external** tables didn't drop, with the following error:

```
[Code: 1, SQL State: 08S01]  Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Failed to load storage handler:  Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler)
```

**How can I safely delete the tables?**

I tried using:

```
 delete from TBL_COL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=[myexternaltableID];
 delete from TBL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=[myexternaltableID];
 delete from TBLS where TBL_ID=[myexternaltableID];
```

But it didn't work with the following error message:

```
[Code: 10297, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10297]: Attempt to do update or delete on table sys.TBLS that is not transactional
```

Thank you,

*NB: I know a schema is supposed to be deleted more safely with HiveQL but on this particular case, this was not done this way.*

Comment: You are trying to modify the metastore? Why can you not drop the table from Hive?

Comment: `storage handler.org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler` kind of tells that the table is (was?) a HBase/Phoenix-backed table, i.e. has nothing to do with deleting `/user/abc/`.

Comment: @mazaneicha We stopped the Hbase service a few months ago, that could be it. Thanks!

Comment: @OneCricketeer The drop command fails with the "Code: 1, SQL State: 08S01" error.

Comment: You shouldn't need to touch the metastore. You can drop tables/databases from Hive - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase

Comment: @OneCricketeer In this particular case, the Hive commands didn't work because the tables were corrupt. The metastore was the correct solution for those external tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a supplementary answer to @Eve's above, she has missed some delete queries about partitions. All delete queries of hive metastore below:

```sql
--Get the tbl_id of the table waited to be dropped at first, the left steps are all based on this.
select TBL_ID from TBLS where tbl_name = 'your_table_name';

--Now we can start the delete operations with the id we got above.
delete from TABLE_PARAMS where TBL_ID=tblid;
delete from TBL_COL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=tblid;
delete from TBL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=tblid;
delete from PARTITION_KEY_VALS where PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=tblid);
delete from PARTITION_PARAMS where part_id in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=tblid);
delete from PART_COL_STATS where PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=tblid);
delete from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=tblid;
delete from PARTITION_KEYS where tbl_id = tblid;
delete from TBLS where TBL_ID=tblid;
```

The same notice: ***Order is important!***

Comment: Approved this answer instead of mine since it has more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Eve Thanks for the improvement to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to delete the tables from **Hive Metastore** (PostgreSQL) with

```sql
delete from "TABLE_PARAMS" where "TBL_ID"='[myexternaltableID]';
delete from "TBL_COL_PRIVS" where "TBL_ID"='[myexternaltableID]';
delete from "TBL_PRIVS" where "TBL_ID"='[myexternaltableID]';
delete from "TBLS" where "TBL_ID"='[myexternaltableID]';
```

*NB: Order is important.*

Comment: your answer is effective, it's good for me, but missed the delete querys about partitions, I have supplemented the sql statement in the following answer.